# What is the .NET equivalent of STARTED in WireMock?

Tags: .net, wiremock

I am implementing [Stateful Behaviour in WireMock.NET](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Scenarios-and-States) . There is [some nice example code](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/) for the java equivalent (WireMock).

The .NET documentation is clear except for one thing. This code in java

```
.whenScenarioStateIs(STARTED)
```

is clear but I cannot find out how to code this in .NET . What is the .NET equivalent of this code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a source code of WireMock.Net.

https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/blob/8f34291ea94f92dafef724eb0845acb5560a35a4/src/WireMock.Net/Admin/Scenarios/ScenarioStateModel.cs

There is an bool property Started. So may be it helps you?

And here is example of StatefulBehaviorTests
https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/blob/0ff23a3d155217db72edc3f817da5bd49758954c/test/WireMock.Net.Tests/StatefulBehaviorTests.cs

There is an WhenStateIs method